# Unable to Connect to Local Server from React Native App on Windows Subsystem for Android (WSA)

Tags: android, react-native

I am currently developing a React Native app for Android and testing it on the Windows Subsystem for Android (WSA). I am trying to make a POST request to my local server using axios like so: `axios.post('http://10.0.2.2:3001/api')`. This works perfectly when I test it on an Android emulator, but it fails when I test it on WSA.

I have confirmed that the issue is not with network connectivity in WSA, and I have added the `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />` line in the `AndroidManifest.xml` file.

I understand that `10.0.2.2` is used in Android emulators to access the host machine, but I suspect WSA might be using a different IP address. If this is the case, what should I use instead of `10.0.2.2` for WSA?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: Use the local ip of that machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I’m glad to report that I’ve found a solution to my problem thanks to `@blackapps` comment. The issue was indeed related to the IP address used to access the local server from the Windows Subsystem for Android (WSA).

Instead of using `10.0.2.2` (which is typically used for Android emulators), I used the local IP address of my machine in the axios call.